# backgroundWorker array in a loop

Tags: c#

Im adding items to a listview, but i need to be able to run a thread for each item to get more data for that item (takes longer to get)
this is just a little sample im trying for now, but for some reason the thread prints the name of about 5 items or so then waits the 5seconds

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)e.Argument);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

.

```
BackgroundWorker[] threadArray = new BackgroundWorker[items.Count];

int gIndex = -1;
foreach (Item gItem in items.Values)
{
    gIndex++;

    ItemDescription ID = getDescription(gItem.id);

    _ListViewAddRow(gIndex, ID.name, ID.url);

    threadArray[gIndex] = new BackgroundWorker();
    threadArray[gIndex].DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    threadArray[gIndex].RunWorkerAsync(ID.name);
}
```

Comment: That's what I'd expect it to do from this code. What are you expecting?

Comment: I expect it to wait the 5 seconds before it prints the next item, but its printing about 5 - 7 items, then waiting the 5 seconds, then printing another 5 - 7 items

Comment: The background workers are running in parallel, so you're starting a thread for each item at roughly the same time, they all print first and then they're waiting 5 seconds, in parallel. They don't execute one after the other.

Comment: oh i see, so how would i pass each item to the background thread, and make it start from the 1st one then wait the 5 seconds then move on to the 2nd item?

Comment: I'd just use one background worker in this case, in your `foreach` loop, build a list of the names then pass that as the argument to the worker, then have a loop in `DoWork` to do the work on each one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

> > as @steve has mention
> >     use one background worker.

```
     BackgroundWorker threadArray = new BackgroundWorker;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (Item gItem in items.Values)
        {//your code

                list.Add(ID.name); 
         }
    threadArray.RunWorkerAsync(list);
```

> > now in dowork do a cast the value to string list back
> >     Do work method

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     List<string> genericlist = e.Argument as List<string>;//cast
      for (int i = 0; i < genericlist.Count; i++) {
           Console.WriteLine(genericlist[i]);
           Thread.Sleep(5000);
       }

}
```